# or_where inside where function active records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I would like to ask if anyone of you know how to place a or_where inside a where in codeigniter?

I would like to create a query as shown below

```
select *
from table
where
(
  (in = 0 and call_in = 1) or
  (out = 0 and call_out = 1)
) and
mid = 0
ORDER BY id DESC
limit 1
```

I have created something like this

```
$result = $mysql_handler->select('*')
                        ->from("table")
                        ->where(
                               array(
                                 "in"       => 0,
                                 "call_in"  => 1
                               )
                          )
                        ->or_where(
                              array(
                                 "out"      => 0,
                                 "call_out" => 1
                              )
                         )
                        ->where("mid", 0)
                        ->order_by("id", "DESC")
                        ->limit(1)
                        ->get();
```

But I know this is not right since this code will produce something like this

```
select *
from table
where
   (in = 0 and call_in = 1) or
   (out = 0 and call_out = 1) and
   mid = 0
ORDER BY id DESC
limit 1
```

I thinking of placing the or_where inside the where clause but I'm not sure if this is correct or how to do it. Please advice thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot combine `where` and `or_where` as you wanted. `or_where` can be used where only `OR` queries needed. You can try this for your solution

```
    $this->db->from('table');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('((in = 0 and call_in = 1) OR (out = 0 and call_out = 1))');
    $this->db->where("mid", 0);
    $this->db->order_by("id", "DESC");
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $result=$this->db->get();
```

Or

```
$result = $mysql_handler->select('*')
        ->from("table")
        ->where('((in = 0 and call_in = 1) OR (out = 0 and call_out = 1))')            
        ->where("mid", 0)
        ->order_by("id", "DESC")
        ->limit(1)
        ->get();
```

Comment: Is there a way inside 
    where('((in = 0 and call_in = 1) OR (out = 0 and call_out = 1))')
to make it like a prepared statment? like

    where('((in = ? and call_in = ?) OR (out = ? and call_out = ?))', array(0,1,0,1)) 

I'm not sure if this is possible